# React problem. Star rating input always checked

Tags: reactjs, rating

I'm struggling with finishing my star rating with React. I can't make it render NO STARS checked initially. I'm using a controlled form and the HOC, which has the state and onChange handler.

Here is the implementation:

The HOC:

```
 const withRating = (Component) => {
  class withRating extends PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        ratingStars: ``,
      };

      this.handleRatingChange = this._handleRatingChange.bind(this);
    }

    _handleRatingChange(evt) {
      const value = evt.target.value;
      this.setState(() => ({
        ratingStars: value,
      }));
    }

    render() {
      const {ratingStars} = this.state;

      return (
        <Component
          onRatingChange={this.handleRatingChange}
          ratingStars={ratingStars}
        />
      );
    }
  }
  return WithRating;
};    
export default withRating;
```

And the Star rating component:

```
const RATING_STARS = [`1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`];

const StarRating= (props) => {
  const {
    onRatingChange,
    ratingStars,
  } = props;

  return (
    <div className="add-rating">
      <form
        action="#"
        className="add-rating"
        onSubmit={(evt) => onFormSubmit(evt)}
      >
        <div className="rating">
          <div className="rating__stars">
            {RATING_STARS.map((star) => (
              <React.Fragment key={`star-${star}`}>
                <input
                  className="rating__input"
                  id={`star-${star}`}
                  type="radio"
                  name="rating"
                  value={star}
                  onChange={(evt) => onRatingChange(evt)}
                  checked={ratingStars === star}
                  disabled={isReviewFormBlocked}
                />
                <label className="rating__label" htmlFor={`star-${star}`}>{`Rating ${star} stars`}</label>
              </React.Fragment>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

StarRating.propTypes = {
  onRatingChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  ratingStars: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default StarRating;
```

The initial state in the HOC has an empty string as the initial value, but for some reason, it renders 5 stars. If I change it to `2` it will render 2 stars (same for `1`, `3`, `4`, `5`), but all other values make it render all stars.

Hope you can help, because I spent ages on this tiny problem.

Comment: where do you use `withRating`? You haven't wrapped `StarRating` with your HOC. is that your intention?

Comment: I have component ReviewPage and wrap it there. HOC and StarRating page has comment form and handlers for comment change and form submit. I didn't write it here, because it works fine and the problem is with the rating part.